# Cordova-Based application not and option for newProject

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I made the command line helloworld project and it worked. When I try to build from XCode the option to build a "Cordova-Based" application is not there.  This picture is what it supposed to show.  I don't have the icon.   I went through install like the wiki says, Xcode was closed, then I tried the helloworld, success:), and the New Project Cordova-Based... crap, really...

What I should see
[image]

and what I do see.
[image]

Comment: did u successfully run the installation. coz it worked with me.. try installing the newer versions of cordova

Comment: I did, I noticed it added some paths.  I will try to reinstall again.

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot about it since I answered it.  Thanks for the bump.

Comment: It is not a problem with 2.0. Create Project icon removed from the new project window. As mentioned here: http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/improvements-in-cordova-2-0-0-for-ios/#comments You must use the command-line utility to create a Cordova 2.0 project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran the 1.9 installer and it showed up in Xcode.

Comment: I'm running XCode 4.2 (4D199), and I have the same problem. Can you please tell me what "1.9 installer" is, and where can I find it ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: I think the I googled it or searched the Cordova site.  The answer above this one may be more appropriate, did you check that out?

Comment: No, the answer above is too complicated for me to apply. I found your solution was the best. I googled to get the result of phoneGap 1.9 & installed it into MACOSX. It worked great ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4):

this option was deleted in Cordova 2.xx
you must use the command lines
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_command-line_index.md.html#Command-Line%20Usage